# What does it mean when your javascript is rendered like this?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I was looking at the page source for an ASP.NET page I wrote and noticed that my javascript was being rendered like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // <![CDATA[
   document.write('<script src="/_layouts/myProject/js/jquery.min.js?rev=sEo7zNI93reYIUNwemPM%2BQ%3D%3D"></' + 'script>');
   // ]]>
</script>
```

Does anyone know :

1. Why there are commented out CDATA
   tags around my script include?  Do these even do anything?
2. Why it's using a `document.write` inside of the script tag to include... another script tag?

Comment: How are you adding the javascript to the page? What DOCTYPE is the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because text nodes in XML that may contain HTML (but shouldn't be parsed as such) should be in [CDATA blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA). Because the block definition is not valid JavaScript, it is commented out.
2. I'm not sure why. I don't think they are downloaded any differently (I imagine a JavaScript disabled browser won't ever download JavaScript files anyway).

Answer (score -1):

Basically the commented CDATA tag is for browsers which doesn't support javascript and for the second one its inserting another javascript file to the page.